# what is the meaning of yellow color label in github?

Tags: github

[Github label essue ,what is the meaning of yellow label in istio "kind/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZxez.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is more for Github community.

It all depends from people who have write access to repository. As mentioned in [Github Help](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-labels)

> Anyone with read access to a repository can view and search the
>   repository’s labels. To create, edit, apply, or delete a label, you
>   must have write access to the repository.

So for example as you mentioned, `Istio` have yellow label for all `kind/` labels but for example in [Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/labels?page=2&sort=name-asc) repository, `kind/` have 3 different colors.

[Here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-labels#using-default-labels) you have information about default labels like bug. documentation, duplicate, etc.

If you would create your own project on github and want to create issue, you have default labels like below.
Later you can edit it.

[image]

**In short, color of labels in each project depends on their owners.**